# Python Flask Permitir Cross-Origin requests de imagenes

Tags: python, flask, cors

Estoy intentando hacer una llamada POST a una api que he creado en Flask. He añadido flask_cors para permitir el "cross-origin".

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```

Basicamente lo que quiero es mandar una imagen a mi api, hacer cosas con esta imagen, y devolver una respuesta.

En principio todo funciona bien, siempre y cuando en el header el content type sea

> content-type: 'text/plain'

Sin embargo si cambio el content-type a

> 'content-type: image/jpeg'

me sale este error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://direccionurl.com/api. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

He intentado de todo y no funciona nada. Según la [documentacion de mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) este tipo de llamadas se llaman Preflighted requests y lo que hace es mandar OPTIONS al servidor primero para asegurarse de que es seguro hacer la siguiente llamada (en este caso mandar una imagen). Pero haga lo que haga me sale el error.

Es la primera vez que uso Flask, y no soy muy experto en estas cosas. Alguien tiene alguna idea de como resolver esto?

Javascript (imageFile es un objeto [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)):

```
axios.post('http://direccionurl.com/api', imageFile,
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': imageFile.type
      }
    }
  ).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error');
  });
```

Servidor Flask:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from PIL import Image

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/", methods = ['GET'])
def root():
  return "hello world"

@app.route("/api/", methods = ['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def predict():
  img = request.data
  print(img)
  return "It worked?"

if __name__ == '__main__':
 app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

Estas son las cabeceras de la llamada cuando hago POST:

> Status 301, Method OPTIONS

**Response Headers:**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Content-Length: 347
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 15 Feb 2019 10:55:40 GMT
Location: http://direccionurl.com/api/
Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.7.1
Vary: Origin
```

**Request Headers**:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xm…plication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host: direccionurl.com
Origin: http://localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linu…) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0
```

Gracias!

Comment: Quizás entre las cabeceras que responde el servidor no está la `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type`. Más útil que el código podría ser el ver exactamente qué cabeceras envía el navegador y qué responde el servidor. Puedes acceder a ellas desde el panel para desarrolladores (F12), panel de red.

Comment: Hola @abulafia, he añadido las cabezeras a ver si eso ayuda un poco a entender el problema. Una solución sería mandar la imagen como texto directament y luego convertirla a imagen otra vez cuando la reciba el servidor, pero me gustaría entender por qué está pasando esto.

Comment: cambia la siguiente linea a esto : `cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})`

Comment: por curiosidad que es `imageFile.type`

Comment: Hola @JackNavaRow perdona que haya tardado tiempo en contestar. Voy a probarlo y te digo. imageFile.type es simplemente el string "image/jpeg"

Comment: @JackNavaRow por desgracia no ha funcionado.